# Изменение цвета при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: html, css

При нажатии на любую из кнопок должен меняться `background-color` на `#fff`, как на скрине.
JS не использую, пока что пишу на чистом html/css.

[image: Da]

```css
.portfolio-btn {
  padding: 10px 33px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 27px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #393939;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  transition: all .1s ease-in;
}

.portfolio-btn:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-btns-row-wrapper">
  <div class="portfolio-btn">All</div>
  <div class="portfolio-btn">Web</div>
  <div class="portfolio-btn">Apps</div>
  <div class="portfolio-btn">Icons</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы применялся `focus` для `div` необходимо добавить `tabindex`

```css
.portfolio-btn {
  padding: 10px 33px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 27px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #393939;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  transition: all .1s ease-in;
}

.portfolio-btn:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-btns-row-wrapper">
  <div class="portfolio-btn" tabindex="0">All</div>
  <div class="portfolio-btn" tabindex="0">Web</div>
  <div class="portfolio-btn" tabindex="0">Apps</div>
  <div class="portfolio-btn" tabindex="0">Icons</div>
</div>
```

или использовать `button`

```css
.portfolio-btn {
  padding: 10px 33px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 27px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #393939;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  transition: all .1s ease-in;
}

.portfolio-btn:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-btns-row-wrapper">
  <button class="portfolio-btn">All</button>
  <button class="portfolio-btn">Web</button>
  <button class="portfolio-btn">Apps</button>
  <button class="portfolio-btn">Icons</button>
</div>
```

Comment: А как задать дефолтное значение? Т.е., при заходе на страницу кнопка All уже была бы выбрана.   И можно ли сделать так, что при нажатии на другую часть экрана выделение не сбрасывалось, т.е. нажатие на другую кнопку меняет цвет, а на экран — нет?

Comment: @Bumbazzz - для этого необходимо использовать ```js``` или  ``input radio```

Comment: @Bumbazzz пример https://jsfiddle.net/nf36xvy7/

Answer (score 0):

Ну и вариант на JS на всякий пожарный.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.portfolio-btn').forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    let target = event.target.closest('.portfolio-btn')
    if(target) {
      let oldActive = target.closest('.portfolio-btns-row-wrapper').querySelector('.portfolio-btn--active');
      if(oldActive) oldActive.classList.remove('portfolio-btn--active');
      target.classList.add('portfolio-btn--active')
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.portfolio-btn {
  padding: 10px 33px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 27px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #393939;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  transition: all .1s ease-in;
}

.portfolio-btn--active {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-btns-row-wrapper">
  <div class="portfolio-btn">All</div>
  <div class="portfolio-btn">Web</div>
  <div class="portfolio-btn">Apps</div>
  <div class="portfolio-btn">Icons</div>
</div>
```